# Angular2 Best practice for routing null path

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, local-storage

I want to set the routing for null path.

While login, getting the role of the user and set the redirect url in the local storage according to the user role which I have to set as the default routing url for null path in app.routing.ts which is included as the routing file in app.module.ts.

I tried like:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: localStorage.getItem('redirectUrl'),
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}, {
 path: '',
 component: AdminLayoutComponent,
 children: [
    {
        path: 'dashboard', 
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }]
}];
```

But while compiling the typescript, it is showing the following error:

*ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'localStorage', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol AppRoutes in /var/www/SSNW/client/src/app/app.routing.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/SSNW/client/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/SSNW/client/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /var/www/SSNW/client/src/app/app.module.ts*

Next alternative is to create a component and specify that in the null path component.

What is the best practice to do it.

Comment: works fine on my local with `angular5` which version you are using

Comment: Sometimes it is compiling success as you told. but the error can come sometimes. I can't predict  the time when the error come.